# INNER join Return Not Returning total Results

Tags: mysql

trade_data Table

---

id symbol action price percent

---

1    1      Buy   3.4    50

---

2    1      SELL   3.8   25

---

3    2      sell   45    75

---

3    2      buy    25.2  50

---

symbol Table

---

id  name

---

1   RCC

---

2   REG

---

---

```
SELECT SUM( IF( trade_data.action =  'BUY', price, 0 ) ) AS  'BUYSUM',
       SUM( IF( trade_data.action =  'SELL', price, 0 ) ) AS  'BUYSELL', 
       AVG( trade_data.percent ) AS peravg, symbol. * 
FROM  `trade_data` 
INNER JOIN  `symbol` ON trade_data.symbol = symbol.id
```

This Query Gives me One Row But there Are Two Row are available at this Condition.
But When I change the query As

```
SELECT trade_data.* , symbol. * 
FROM  `trade_data` 
INNER JOIN  `symbol` ON trade_data.symbol = symbol.id
```

Then this Query Gives me Exact 2 Rows.

Comment: please show your records in the two tables that you think should be in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by with aggregate  function
ex.

```
SELECT SUM( IF( trade_data.action =  'BUY', price, 0 ) ) AS  'BUYSUM', SUM( IF( trade_data.action =  'SELL', price, 0 ) ) AS  'BUYSELL', AVG( trade_data.percent ) AS peravg, symbol. *
```

FROM  `trade_data` 
INNER JOIN  `symbol` ON trade_data.symbol = symbol.id group by symbol.id

Comment: Thanks I got the wanted result Now.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` in mysql gives you the sum of the specified column from the result rows. So here, SUM(price) will give you the Total of price, adding each row's price value. And the total is always a single value due to which you get a single row output.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AVG()` and `SUM()` functions , that is why you are getting a single reord

```
The AVG() Function
The AVG() function returns the average value of a numeric column.


The SUM() Function
The SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column.
```

If you have multiple `trade_data.symbol = symbol.id` (more than 1 id) you can use a `GROUP BY` to get sum and average  of each record with similar id , since you have only 1 same  `symbol.id` and `trade_data.symbol` you will get only one record .